# Monodevelop targeting Mono on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm new to monodevelop and mono, so please forgive me if that is very simple/dumb question.

I'm trying to force MonoDevelop target Mono on Windows 10. So I went through the steps described here: http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/
Started Monodevelop and changed Tools/Options/Projects/.Net Runtimes to Mono 5.12.0

After this, the simple "Hello World" console application doesn't work.

**1)** Intellisense shows errors like "Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported", the same about string and Console types

**2)** When I try to build it, I'm getting an error:

```
Target _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(612,5): error MSB4036: The "Message" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory.
Done building target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in project "TestMonoConsole.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

It looks like it targets wrong Microsoft.Common.targets file (use .Net default one instead of the one located in Mono folder).

**3)** Then I tried changing replacing $(MSBuildBinPath) to path inside Mono folder  but that caused other errors like

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Mono\lib\mono\msbuild\15.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(168,4):
>   error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Does anyone know what step did I miss? How can I force Monodevelop to target mono instead of .Net Framework properly?

Comment: My personal opinion is that you should not waste your time on such, https://blog.lextudio.com/status-of-monodevelop-xamarin-studio-253da80d022c What's wrong with .NET Framework and Visual Studio, and why cannot you use them?

Comment: @LexLi, I need to develop an app that will work on Windows and Mac using c#. My first thought was to use mono + gtk#. Are there better options?

Comment: On IDE side, use Visual Studio and Visual Studio for Mac (JetBrains Rider is another option). For UI framework, GTK# is not the best for Windows and macOS, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea